# The exponential of a real matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be a $n \times n$ real matrix such that $Exp(A) \in SO(n)$, is it necessarily that $A$ is anti-symmetric?

Comment: Seen [this](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix#Lie_algebra)?

Comment: Why is $Exp(tA) \in SO(n)$ for all $t$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is false. Let
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&\pi\cr-4\pi&0\cr}.
$$
Then the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\pm2\pi i$. So 
$$SAS^{-1}=\pmatrix{0&2\pi\cr-2\pi&0\cr}$$
for an appropriate matrix $S$. But
$$
\exp(A)=S^{-1}\exp(SAS^{-1})S=S^{-1}I_2S=I_2
$$
is in $SO(2)$, because for all real $t$ we have
$$
\exp\pmatrix{0&t\cr-t&0\cr}=\pmatrix{\cos t&\sin t\cr-\sin t&\cos t\cr}.
$$ Yet $A$ is not antisymmetric.

Comment: Notice that the question raised by Hezudao about the argument linked to in J.M.'s comment plays a key role.